# extracting sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list consisting of DateObjects and strings:

```
lis = {DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], "a", "b", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}], "c", "d", "e", DateObject[{2019, 1, 3}], "f"};
```

I would like to construct a function that takes as its argument a `DateObject`, and have it return all the following string elements that follow it in `lis` until the next occurrence of a `DateObject` in the list.

If the argument is `DateObject[{2019,1,2}]`, then the return would be:

```
res = {"c","d","e"}
```

There probably are many ways to do this. I tried using `SplitBy[lis, DateObjectQ]` then `SequenceCases` but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[lis, {DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}], a:Except[_DateObject] ..., _DateObject} :> a]
```

> {"c", "d", "e"}

Also

```
Cases[lis,
  {___, DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}], a : Except[_DateObject] ..., _DateObject, ___} :> a, All]
```

> {"c", "d", "e"}

Answer (score 5):

```
lis = {
   DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], "a", "b",
   DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}], "c", "d", "e",
   DateObject[{2019, 1, 3}], "f"};

f[x_] := Rest[FirstCase[Split[lis, Head[#2] =!= DateObject &], {x, ___}]]

res = f[DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}]]
```

> {"c", "d", "e"}

Answer (score 4):

Straight forward solution:

```
dateExtract[date_DateObject, lis_List] :=
    FirstPosition[lis, date] //
    Drop[lis, First@#] & //
    TakeWhile[#, Not@*DateObjectQ] &
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f[data_List, d_DateObject] := Append[data, d -> {}]
f[{dates___, d_ -> l_List}, s_String] := {dates, d -> Append[l, s]}
lookup = Fold[f, {}, lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can now use this lookup like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> `{"c", "d", "e"}`

Answer (score 2):

We can easily build a lookup - table with

```
look = 
  GroupBy[Split[lis, MatchQ[#2, _String] &],
  First -> Rest, 
  Flatten];
```

and then ask for

```
look[DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}]]
```

{"c", "d", "e"}

Alternatively, we can use `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[look, DateObject[{2019, 1, 3}], {}]
```

{"f"}

With a small change of the grouping argument

```
look = 
  GroupBy[Split[lis, MatchQ[#2, _String] &], 
  First @* First -> Rest,
  Flatten]
```

we could more comfortably ask:

```
look[{2019, 1, 2}]
```

{"c", "d", "e"}